# Turborepo Import Aliases

Tags: typescript, pnpm, turborepo

I'm setting up a monorepo for a couple Typescript projects I'm working on and I'm having issues with import aliasing. My directory structure is as follows

```
project/
  apps/
    streaming/
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      src/
        handlers/
          KafkaHandler.ts
  packages/
    shared-utils/
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
      src/
        clients/
          Kafka.ts
    tsconfig/
      base.json
```

`project/packages/tsconfig/base.json`

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "display": "Default",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ES2019",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}
```

`project/packages/shared-utils/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "baseUrl": "dist/src",
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

`project/apps/streaming/tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "tsconfig/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src"
  ],
}
```

`project/apps/streaming/package.json`

```json
{
  "author": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "kafkajs": "^2.2.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "prompts": "^2.4.2",
    "shared-utils": "workspace:*",
    "tiny-typed-emitter": "^2.1.0",
    "tsconfig": "workspace:*"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.199",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
    "@types/prompts": "^2.4.6",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "main": "./dist/index.ts",
  "name": "streaming",
  "packageManager": "pnpm@8.6.10",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "clean": "rm -rf dist && rm -rf node_modules",
    "clean_build": "pnpm run clean && pnpm i && pnpm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "compile": "tsc"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

`projects/packages/shared-utils/src/clients/Kafka.ts` has a default exported module which contains the methods I use to interact with Kafka. I'd like to be able to import the module in `project/apps/streaming` using a path like so

```js
import {Kafka} from 'shared-utils/clients'

/* OR */

import Kafka from 'shared-utils/clients/Kafka'
```

I've seen several sources on typescript import aliasing, but it's difficult to get a straight answer on this. Currently I have `index.ts` files in each directory in `src` that bubble up to a root `index.ts` file. This is pretty painful because imports require 2 lines

```js
import {Clients} from 'shared-utils'
import Kafka = Clients.Kafka
```

At this point I'm not even sure if I should be trying to configure this through Typescript, pnpm, or Turborepo. I'm hoping someone can point out what configuration needs to be changed to allow me to import in the way described above. Thanks!

Comment: What does your Kafka.ts export look like?